# Easier way to run Entity Framework Core queries in LinqPad with builtin Linq to SQL driver?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, linqpad

**Note:** This is an old question. With **LinqPad 5** you had the limitations I've described below, because it isn't written in .NET Core. But now you can use the newer [LinqPad 6 or 7](https://www.linqpad.net/Download.aspx), which fully supports Entity Framework Core including drivers for multiple database systems.

---

I want to **analyze Entity Framework Core queries,** which I copied from existing code into LinqPad like

```
UserQuery this_context;
void Main()
{
    this_context = this;
    var validationResult = (

        from ProjectInfo pi in this_context.GetAll<ProjectInfo>()
        join GeneralInformation gi in this_context.GetAll<GeneralInformation>() 
                                   on pi.Id equals gi.Id into gpi
        from gps in gpi.DefaultIfEmpty()

        select new { ... }).ToList();
}
```

I know, that Linqpad **does not support .NET Core,** so I have to tweak it a bit - for this purpose I have created an Extension method as follows:

```
public static class Ext
{
    public static  IEnumerable GetAll<T>(this UserQuery uq)
    where T: new()
    {
        return GetAll(uq, new T());
    }

    private static  IEnumerable GetAll<T>(this UserQuery uq, T a)
    {
        switch (a)
        {
            case ProjectInfo v:
                return uq.ProjectInfo.Select(s => s);
            case GeneralInformation v:
                return uq.GeneralInformation.Select(s => s);

            // ... many more cases like the above 

            default: // unknown type
                throw new TypeAccessException($"Unsupported type {a.GetType().FullName}");
        }
    }
    
}
```

The overloaded `GetAll` function is required to get the type - it just creates an empty new object and passes it in so that the switch statement can properly deduct the correct type and return the right query.

That works fine, but it is **a lot of effort** to put in every single type into the switch statement.

**So my question is:**

How can this be achieved in a smarter way, i.e. without having to specify every single entity type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LINQPad's `UserQuery` object seems to have a method that is exactly what you want:

```
public static class Ext {
    public static IEnumerable GetAll<T>(this UserQuery uq) =>uq.GetTable(typeof(T));
}
```

I believe you could stay type safe with:

```
public static IQueryable<T> GetAll<T>(this UserQuery uq) => (IQueryable<T>)uq.GetTable(typeof(T));
```

Using your original `IEnumerable` version causes all the tables to be loaded into memory one by one and then the LINQ executed on the objects. Using `IQueryable<T>` translates the query to SQL - this may not be desirable in the cases where LINQ to SQL and EF differ in translation (for no good reason), but I could see issues with EF specific capabilities (e.g. `Include` and `DbFunctions`, though I have written empty `Include` extension methods to hide that some).

If the `IQueryable` version doesn't work, an `ITable<>` version may:

```
public static ITable<T> GetAll<T>(this UserQuery uq) where T : class => (ITable<T>)uq.GetTable(typeof(T));
```

Comment: Works fine, that was exactly what I was looking for. Many thanks! The type safe version however thwows an InvalidOperationException for unknown reason.

Comment: Perhaps an `.AsQueryable()` is needed after the `GetTable`? I don't get an error when I test it using a connection to MS SQL. I added another typesafe version that may work better.

Comment: Both typed versions are throwing `InvalidOperationException: Could not translate expression 'Table(ProjectInfo).Cast().GroupJoin(Table(GeneralInformation).Cast(), pi => pi.Id ...` in my case, while the untyped version (the 1st one in your answer) works fine

Comment: I finally found a way to get it working with typed result: `public static IEnumerable<T> GetAll<T>(this UserQuery uq) => (IEnumerable<T>)uq.GetTable(typeof(T));` - this works fine, so the reason was that the interface classes `IQueryable<T>` and `ITable<T>` aren't 100% compatible with Linq.

Comment: @Matt I don't think that is right - `IQueryable<T>` is the foundation of LINQ (to SQL/EF). If you cast to `IEnumerable<T>` I would be concerned you are pulling in the entire table into memory and not executing a SQL query but rather LINQ to Objects, which can be subtly different.

Comment: That is only for quick analysis in Linqpad and not for optimization purpose. I agree I would prefer IQeryable<T>, but for my query it is not working.